# GetColumnName() LinqToExcel for csv file throw error The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$.txt'

Tags: c#, csv, linq-to-excel

I am using linqToExcel dll from to read a csv file and query the csv file the data . I also neeed the names of columns (Header ) from csv .

when i try to run the following code as per the [document mentioned](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel#query-column-names)

its throw an error message as follow :

**The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$.txt'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.**

my code is as follow :

```
string pathToExcelFile = ""
        + @"c:\users\rahul\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\csv\student.csv";

            string sheetName = "student";

            var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathToExcelFile);

            //get all sheet names 
            var sheetNames = excelFile.GetWorksheetNames();

            //get column name from csv 
            var columnNames = excelFile.GetColumnNames(sheetName);
```

To get the correct sheet name i tried to use excelFile.GetWorksheetNames() but its return zero records.

Note: I am using csv file and when i open same csv file in MS Excel its shows me 
student as Sheet Name even i tried with sheet1 as well.

Comment: Make sure you have Microsoft office Access installed.Also try to change the default sheet name from sheet1 to something else

Comment: Have you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution:

```
IEnumerable<string> columnNames;
var workSheetName = excel.GetWorksheetNames().FirstOrDefault();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(workSheetName))
{
    // CSV files do not have worksheet names
    var worksheet = excel.Worksheet();
    if (worksheet == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Unable to extract data. The file contains no data");
    }
    var row = worksheet.FirstOrDefault();
    if (row == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Unable to extract data. The file contains no rows.");
    }
    columnNames = row.ColumnNames;

}
else
{
    columnNames = excel.GetColumnNames(workSheetName);
}

if (columnNames == null || !columnNames.Any())
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Unable to extract column information.");
}
```

Comment: I've been searching all day for this! Thank you!